# C++ Service Error While Starting : Could not Start the Service on Local Computer

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, windows-services

I have created a Win32 Service using C++ and installed to the Services Successfully.

Now While I try Starting the service from Services.msc , I am getting the Error:
Could not start the Service on Local Computer . Error 2: The system can not find the File specified.

Here is the code snippet I am defining in the Service Entry Point:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "Windows.h"
#include "Winsvc.h"
#include "time.h"


SERVICE_STATUS m_ServiceStatus;
SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE m_ServiceStatusHandle;
BOOL bRunning=true;
void WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv);
void WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler(DWORD Opcode);
BOOL InstallService();
BOOL DeleteService();
void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  if(argc>1)
  {
    if(strcmp(argv[1],"-i")==0)
    {
      if(InstallService())
        printf("\n\nService Installed Sucessfully\n");
      else
        printf("\n\nError Installing Service\n");
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[1],"-u")==0)
    {
      if(DeleteService())
        printf("\n\nService UnInstalled Sucessfully\n");
      else
        printf("\n\nError UnInstalling Service\n");
    }
    else
    {
      printf("\n\nUnknown Switch Usage\n\nFor Install use WindowService -i\n\nFor UnInstall use WindowService -u\n");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY DispatchTable[]=
                {{"myService",ServiceMain},{NULL,NULL}};
    StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(DispatchTable);
  }
 // DeleteService();
  //return 0;
}

void WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv)
{
  DWORD status;
  DWORD specificError;
  m_ServiceStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32;
  m_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
  m_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP;
  m_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
  m_ServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
  m_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
  m_ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 0;

  m_ServiceStatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler("myService", 
                                            ServiceCtrlHandler); 
  if (m_ServiceStatusHandle == (SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE)0)
  {
    return;
  }
  m_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
  m_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
  m_ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 0;
  if (!SetServiceStatus (m_ServiceStatusHandle, &m_ServiceStatus))
  {
  }
system("start c:\\progra~1\\intern~1\\iexplore.exe http://www.google.com");
  //strcat("Win1", "1.exe");
  /*bRunning=true;
  while(bRunning)
  {
    //Sleep(3000);
    //Place Your Code for processing here....
       //printf("\nThe Service is Running Now...\n");


  }*/
  return;
}

void WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler(DWORD Opcode)
{
  switch(Opcode)
  {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_PAUSE: 
      m_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_PAUSED;
      break;
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE:
      m_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
      break;
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
      m_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
      m_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
      m_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
      m_ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 0;

      SetServiceStatus (m_ServiceStatusHandle,&m_ServiceStatus);
      bRunning=false;
      break;
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE:
      break; 
  }
  return;
}

BOOL InstallService()
{
  char strDir[1024];
  HANDLE schSCManager,schService;
  GetCurrentDirectory(1024,strDir);
  strcat(strDir,"\\Debug\\WindowService.exe"); 
  schSCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL,NULL,SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);

  if (schSCManager == NULL) 
    return false;
  LPCTSTR lpszBinaryPathName=strDir;

  schService = CreateService(schSCManager,"myService", 
        "my_Service", // service name to display

     SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, // desired access 

     SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, // service type 

     SERVICE_DEMAND_START, // start type 

     SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL, // error control type 

     lpszBinaryPathName, // service's binary 

     NULL, // no load ordering group 

     NULL, // no tag identifier 

     NULL, // no dependencies

     NULL, // LocalSystem account

     NULL); // no password


  if (schService == NULL)
    return false; 

  CloseServiceHandle(schService);
  return true;
}

BOOL DeleteService()
{
  HANDLE schSCManager;
  SC_HANDLE hService;
  schSCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL,NULL,SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);

  if (schSCManager == NULL)
    return false;
  hService=OpenService(schSCManager,"myService",SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
  if (hService == NULL)
    return false;
  if(DeleteService(hService)==0)
    return false;
  if(CloseServiceHandle(hService)==0)
    return false;

return true;
}
```

I have taken this code sample from [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/windows_nt_service.aspx?pageflow=FixedWidth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your service's properties in services.msc to see where your exe is expected to run from, and make sure this matches the physical path of the EXE.  Make sure the EXE is actually there.  Check the Event Viewer to see if more info is present about the error.  make sure the code runs properly when not run as a service - making your code run optionally as service and not as service is likely to be very helpful in this regard.  Run thru service installation in the debugger to make sure you are not missing an error code somewhere - did service installation actually work properly end to end?

Answer (score 1):

Where is the location that you have installed your service. DId you check that the service exists in that location.

Are you trying to run it as a network service or local user service.

Comment: Installing the service at my Debug Folder (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\MyProjects\WindowService\Debug) and running as Local User. I am not pretty sure about all your quries so updated the post with whole snippet